# is there a way to access an object within an object?

Tags: java, hashmap, composition

I'm practicing java by building a simple directory. I have 4 Classes. These are:

1. Person
2. Address
3. Contact
4. testClass

I have already finished creating this system and it works the way I want it. I did this by making 3 different arrays for the Person, Address and Contact. To link the Person, Address and Contact together I place them on there respective array with the same index number. (Not literally linking them together, just a way to know which address or contact to access when editing a person).

But now, I want to optimize it. I want to create a single HashMap to hold a person with the address and contacts within it. Please see my code below for more information.

Person.class

```
public class Person {
private long Id;
private firtName;
private Address address;
private Contact contact;

//some setter and getter methods

public Person(Address address, Contact contact) {
this.address = address;
this.contact = contact;
}
}
```

Address.class

```
public class Address {

private String street;
private String city;
private String province;


//some setter and getter methods
}
```

Contact.class

```
public class Contact {

private long Phone;
private String Email;

//some setter and getter methods
}
```

testClass.class

```
public class testClass {

public static void main(String[] args) {
HashMap<Integer, Person> person = new HashMap<Integer, Person>();

person.put(1, new Person(new Address(), new Contact)));
person.get(1).setStreet("place");

}

}
```

My question is, on this line of code in the testClass

```
person.get(1).setStreet("place");
```

is there a way to directly access/edit the person's address or contact without creating a separate array or method?

Comment: I didn't understand whats the problem here. What is "directly accessing", what array/method do you talk about?

Comment: Have getter methods for Address and Contacts and modify them.

Comment: Little addition on your naming. Contact might be mistaken for person while you're rather meaning contact information. And calling a collection of persons person in singular is confusing too. It would be easier to read as indexedPeople or peopleMap or just people at least.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
private Address address;
private Contact contact;
```

If you were to make these `public` instead of `private` you would be able to access them directly like so:

```
Person person = new Person(new Address(), new Contact());

Person p = person.get(1);
String city = p.address.getCity();
String email = p.contact.getEmail();
```

However this violates the principle of encapsulation (you should hide your inner fields and allow access only through methods).

Instead you should create your person class as follows:

```
public class Person {
    private long Id;
    private firtName;
    private Address address;
    private Contact contact;

//some setter and getter methods

    public Person(Address address, Contact contact) {
        this.address = address;
        this.contact = contact;
    }

    public Address getAddress() {
        return address;
    }

    public Contact getContact() {
        return contact;
    }
}
```

and access through

```
Person p = person.get(1);
String city = p.getAddress().getCity();
String email = p.getContact().getEmail();
```

Comment: by making a method getAddress() and getContact() means I'm creating an instance of those 2 classes right? But what if I had to make 100 person, do I still have to make 100 references for each getAddress and getContact? I don't know if that will be a good design.

Comment: You only create an instance of those classes when you use the "new" keyword. After that your Person class is saving a reference to their location in memory, and getAddress is simply returning that same object.

Comment: Small addition to this: You don't necessarily need to pass an address and contact info in the constructor. You could also create setters for those. But this highly depends on your business logic.

Comment: I finally understand the logic behind this. Thank you for all your help! I finally able to run it the way I want it.

Answer (score 1):

When a person is an aggregation of address, contact informations and so on, you should have getters and setters for those. You'd then write this to set street on a person:

```
person.getAddress().setStreet("this and that")
```

and you could also assign a new address whatsoever:

```
person.setAddress(new Address("streeetname", "cityname"))
```

This is a common idiom in Java and the way to go. Having public access objects creates new problems since this kind of access cannot be changed without side-effects in all classes using them.

Comment: my problem with this approach is the number of references I need to make for each getAddress of a person. I can't think of a solution on how can I make an object automatically using a prefix to make theses references distinct.

Comment: Sorry, I don't quite understand the problem here

Comment: Now I get you. It's about me using person instead of person.get(x), right? In my example the person object is one instance of Person. See my comment on the question regarding naming conventions.

Answer (score 1):

What I see here is a dependency inversion issue. Your class `Person` depends on `Address` and `Contact`. In the purest sense the Address and Contact should be Interfaces, so their implementations could be swapped out at runtime.

```
public class Person {
  private long Id;
  private firstName;
  private Address address;
  private Contact contact;

  public Person(Address address, Contact contact) {
    this.address = address;
    this.contact = contact;
  }

  public Address getAddress() {
    return this.address;
  }

  public setAddress(Address address) {
    this.address = address;
  }

  public Contact getContact() {
    return this.contact;
  }

  public setContact(Contact contact) {
    this.contact = contact;
  }

}
```

Then you could access `Address` in the following way:

```
person.get(1).getAddress().setStreet("place");
```