# Accessing setters of object within object

Tags: java, class, object

Say I have two classes:

```
public class Customer {
    private String name;
    private Car car;

    public Customer() {}

    public Customer(String name, Car car) {
        this.name = name;
        this.car = car;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {this.name = name;}

    public String getName() {return this.name;}
    public Car getCar() {return this.car;}
}
```

and

```
public class Car {
    private String brand;

    public Car() {}

    public Car(String brand) {
        this.brand = brand;
    }

    public void setBrand(String brand) {this.brand = brand;}

    public String getBrand() {return this.brand;}
}
```

---

From Martin Konecny's answer in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34459901/is-there-a-way-to-access-an-object-within-an-object), I understand that in order to access the **getters** of `Car` from `Customer`, I would do something like this:

```
Customer c = new Customer("Lefrost", "BMW");
String brand = c.getCar().getBrand();
```

---

But how should I go about accessing the **setters** of `Car` from `Customer`?

I tried the following, which works:

```
// adding setter for 'car' in Customer class
public void setCar(Car car) {this.car = car;}
```

and then changed the data field contents of `Car` like so:

```
c.setCar(new Car("Honda"));
```

But this requires me to create a new `Car` object, and it isn't actually using the setters inside the `Car` class.

---

**How exactly do I access the setters of `Car` from `Customer`?**

**And if there is no good way to do so, is there a better way to change the data field contents of `Car` from `Customer`?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just call `getCar` and then on that returned object call the `setBrand` method:

```
c.getCar().setBrand("Honda");
```

The `Car` returned by `getCar()` will be the `Car` stored inside `Customer` and so nothing stops you really from just directly setting the brand on that returned object.

If a `Car` is immutable though, then your attempt:

```
c.setCar(new Car("Honda"));
```

is the only way to achieve that.

Answer (score 0):

If the field for brand isn't final, you can do `c.getCar().setBrand("Honda")`

Answer (score 0):

You need to get the Car Object and then set the property in it:

```
c.setCar(new Car());
c.getCar().setBrand("Honda");
```